# Can time drift even after using NTP?

Tags: time, ntp, drift

We have NTP installed on our servers to keep time on them in sync. Can time of the servers still drift? If yes, how can we detect that? Can we force server to reset after certain max drift?

Comment: If you're running NTP as a daemon, the drift should be minimal unless your reference time sources are themselves not stable (which makes them a poor choice for a reference time source).  If you run NTP once at server startup (not in daemon mode), then you'd suffer from drift over time — fixable by running NTP again.  (I've not checked whether the NTP daemons can be run as a 'single shot' process — but you probably don't run it that way by accident.)  Have you checked the batteries on the real-time clocks on the machines where you have a drift problem?  (Batteries probably aren't a problem.)

Answer (score 4):

This is a very tricky question to answer without knowing a lot more about your time domain setup.

If your time setup is correctly configured then no. All your servers will keep within an acceptable distance of true time. *But* that presumes you have both your own stratum 0 / 1 time receiver and at least 5 external reference sources of a low stratum.

If your time setup is 'closed' wherein you only take time from say your own S0/1 reference source then depending on that source *yes* your servers can drift from UTC but would all remain in sync. This would only really be true if you where using a pure PPS type source that dose not actually provide a timestamp.

If your time setup is 'bad' with say only 1 or 2 external reference servers at a high stratum then if the reference sources become wrong either by accident or through other interference then your servers could be off by a big factor. If all your servers used the same upstream source then as above they *should* all be in sync with each other but could be out against UTC. If all your servers used a different source then they could all be out of sync in comparison with each other & UTC.

To answer the last part of your question next; *No* I wouldn't force any server to do anything (like jumping the time/date) I'd make sure my ntp setup was working correctly so that it always ran with a valid drift file and kept the host in check how it was intended (Over a running period of time)

As to monitoring ntp this can be a tricky one. If you wanted to automate it then you can find scripts on the net which will allow the collection of ntp stats into mrtg that will allow you to plot drift, offset, disposition etc. I have successfully implemented this for a number of hosts and it appears to work quite well. It will give you graphs & alerts if you exceed limits you define. Otherwise you have things like ntpstats and other log files you can trawl through, but I suspect that's what you are trying to avoid.

Please feel free to update your question if you need a better or more specific answer. Hopefully this helps.

You could try [this](http://www.satsignal.eu/ntp/NTPandMRTG.html) link for ideas on monitoring via a script and MRTG there is also a number of plugins for Icinga/Nagios [here](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Network-Protocols/NTP-and-Time) which might be of help. My scripts are based on the examples in the 1st link - but they allow +ive and -ive plots in my RRD files. To do that you need to generate the RRD *first* then run `rrdtool tune <name_of_rrd>.rrd -i ds1:U -a ds1:U`

But I also notice in the source file for ntp-4.2.6p5 I find the following dir `/ntpsnmpd/` which has an interesting `README` which says you can access some values via an SNMP agentx. Have a look - I've not seen that till now & never tested it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Can you provide some ntp stats collection script examples?